# OOM issue in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, out-of-memory

What is the best approach to investigate Out Of Memory issue when running a stored procedure? I have checked the cursor or loop but it looks OK. What usually cause this in a stored procedure?

Comment: Procedural like stored procedure - and especially memory allocation - code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: oh sorry, tag added